# How do I loop two files set in bash?

Tags: bash, loops

I have two set of files. Lets say 10 files. I am trying to access two files in order. They always should go in pair.

```
#p1.01 p1.02 ... p1.05
#p2.01 p2.02 ... p2.05

for i j in p1.* and p2.*
do
    script.pl -input1 $i -input2 $j
    # this will be
    # script.pl -input1 p1.01 -input2 p2.01
    # script.pl -input1 p1.02 -input2 p2.02
    # and so on until 5 pairs
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the pairs always have matching suffixes like in your example, you could do this:

```
for i in p1.* ; do
    j=${i/#p1/p2}
    script.pl -input1 "$i" -input2 "$j"
done
```

Comment: `j=${i/#p1/p2}` is more efficient.

Comment: Thanks, I incorporated that change.

Comment: Thanks. this was more flexible when not known if file number pairs were 25 or 26.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `bash` 4 or later:

```
for suffix in {01..05}; do
    script.pl -input1 p1.$suffix -input2 p2.$suffix
done
```

In earlier versions, you'll have to handle the leading zero(s) yourself. For instance,

```
# Instead of {01..15}
for suffix in 0{1..9} 1{0..5}; do
    script.pl -input1 p1.$suffix -input2 p2.$suffix
done
```

Comment: cool, I had 25 pairs, this worked: Thanks `for suffix in {01..25}
do
        echo  $1.$suffix $2.$suffix
        echo -e "\n"
done
`

Comment: Note that `echo` by itself is equivalent to `echo -e "\n"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do:

```
for f in p1.*; do 
   script.pl -input1 "$f" -input2 "p2.${f#p1.}"
done
```

`${f#p1.}` will strip `p1.` from start of each `p1.*` filename that we are iterating in `for` loop and `p2.${f#p1.}` will make that filename using `p2.` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, using `i` and `j` variables

```
ls p* | sort -t"." -k2n -k1 | paste - - | 
while read i j; do 
  script.pl -input1 "$i" -input2 "$j"; 
done
```

from `ls p* | sort -t"." -k2n -k1 | paste - -` you get,

```
p1.01 p2.01
p1.02 p2.02
... 
p1.05 p2.05
```